# rxjs5 Observable.ajax ignores explicitly set HTTP headers

Tags: ajax, oauth-2.0, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I'm getting my feet wet with redux-observable and OAuth2 authentication. I'm stuck at the point where I have to POST adding Authorization header to my HTTP request. The header is has not been added. Instead, I see any custom-set header names as values of Access-Control-Request-Headers, and that's it.

This is a redux-observable 'epic':

```
const epicAuth = function(action$){
  return action$.ofType(DO_AUTHENTICATE)
    .mergeMap(
      action => Rx.Observable.ajax( authRequest(action.username, action.password))
        .map( response => renewTokens(response))
        .catch(error => Rx.Observable.of({
          type: AJAX_ERROR,
          payload: error,
          error: true,
        }))
    )
}
```

This is my request object:

```
const authRequest = function(username, password){
  return {
    url: TOKEN_PROVIDER + '?grant_type=password&username=' + username + '&password=' + password,
    method: 'POST',
    responseType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic <base64-encoded-user@password>',
    }
  }
}
```

The HTTP headers captured:

```
http://localhost:8082/api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=yyy

OPTIONS /api/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=xxx&password=yyy HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8082
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization
Origin: http://localhost:3000
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive

HTTP/1.1 401 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="MY_REALM/client"
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1098
Date: Wed, 01 Nov 2017 17:57:38 GMT
```

It all ends up with 401 response, since the Authorization header was not sent. I have tested the Oauth2 endpoint manually with Postman tool, and all went well: I've got a valid access token, could renew it, etc. CORS is enabled on server side.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

The client code is working correctly.

You've captured the OPTIONS cors request, which is asking the server if it is OK to POST the Authorization header (see the `Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization`).

Make sure that you've configured CORS correctly on your server.  It shouldn't be trying to authenticate OPTIONS calls.  It should instead be sending a proper response which tells the browser if it is allowed to make the POST call.